# list files inside zip file over 4gb without downloading it all

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I am trying to list all the files inside a ".zip" file without downloading it all.

I have successfully manage to do this with files smaller than 4GB with the following code:

```
def get_list_of_files_from_zip(self, source_bucket, source_key, ignore_hidden_files=True):

    # self.s3 returns boto3.resource('s3') already initialize with the keys 
    s3_object = self.s3.Object(source_bucket, source_key)
    size = s3_object.content_length

    # End of central directory record (EOCD)
    eocd = self._fetch_bytes_from_file(source_bucket, source_key, size - 22, 22)

    # start offset and size of the central directory
    cd_start = convert_to_int(eocd[16:20])
    cd_size = convert_to_int(eocd[12:16])

    # fetch central directory, append EOCD, and open as zipfile!
    cd = self._fetch_bytes_from_file(source_bucket, source_key, cd_start, cd_size)
    zip = ZipFile(BytesIO(cd + eocd))

    list_of_file = []
    for entry in zip.filelist:

        if ignore_hidden_files and (entry.file_size == 0 or is_hidden(entry.filename)):
            continue

        list_of_file.append({"name": entry.filename,
                             "size": entry.file_size})  # On bytes
    return list_of_file

def _fetch_bytes_from_file(self, source_bucket, source_key, start, len):
    """
    range-fetches a S3 key
    """
    end = start + len - 1
    s3_object = self.s3.Object(source_bucket, source_key).get(Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end))
    return s3_object['Body'].read()



def convert_to_int(bytes):

    val = ord(bytes[0]) + (ord(bytes[1]) << 8)
    if len(bytes) > 3:
        val += (ord(bytes[2]) << 16) + (ord(bytes[3]) << 24)
    return val
```

The problem is that I have tried to do the same with a file of 70GB, and what I receive is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-b4cd8dc7616e>", line 1, in <module>
    s3.get_list_of_files_from_zip(bucket_name,key_name)
  File "/Users/.../base.py", line 153, in get_list_of_files_from_zip
    zip = ZipFile(BytesIO(cd + eocd))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 839, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile("Bad magic number for central directory")
BadZipfile: Bad magic number for central directory
```

After doing some research I found out that zip files over 4gb have a different structure

[image: Zip64 file structure]

And according to the [specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) (search for "4.3.15 Zip64 end of central directory locator")

*"The Zip64 end of central directory locator"* should help me to find the *"Zip64 end of central directory record"* that will allow me to extract the start end length of the central directory of the zip64 file.

So what I have done is:

```
size_eocd = 22 # End of central directory record
size_Zip64EndCD = 20
Zip64EndCD = self._fetch_bytes_from_file(source_bucket, source_key, size - (size_eocd + size_Zip64EndCD), size_Zip64EndCD)

# relative offset of the zip64 end of central directory record 8 bytes
relative_offset = convert_to_int(Zip64EndCD[8:16]) 
# result in my example relative_offset = 1811690735, size = 74826134865
```

And here is where I get lost, the documentation says that is the "relative offset of the zip 64 end of central directory" but it doesn't say relative to what offset (size? cd position? ???)

I have try the following but I don't find the "zip64 end of central dir signature" = 0x06064b50

```
"\x50\x4b\x06\x06" in self._fetch_bytes_from_file(source_bucket, source_key, size - relative_offset, 3000)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [zipdetails](https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails) a long time ago to help me understand the internal structure of zip files.

Let's create a zip64 zip file (the `-fz` option will force Zip64).

```
$ zip -fz xx.zip /tmp/Makefile

$ unzip -l xx.zip
Archive:  xx.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     1240  02-05-2020 14:31   tmp/Makefile
---------                     -------
     1240                     1 file
```

If you run `zipdetails` against a zip64 zip file, and look at the end where the central directory data lives, you will see something like this. I've included extra annotation to show the pointer value you need to set. So you need to set the field "*relative offset of the zip64 end of central directory record*" to point to the location of the "*Zip64 end of central directory locator*" field. In this case that is hex 299.

```
0299 ZIP64 END CENTRAL DIR 06064B50  <----------------+ 
     RECORD                                           |
029D Size of record        000000000000002C           |
02A5 Created Zip Spec      1E '3.0'                   |
02A6 Created OS            03 'Unix'                  |
02A7 Extract Zip Spec      2D '4.5'                   |
02A8 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'                |
02A9 Number of this disk   00000000                   |
02AD Central Dir Disk no   00000000                   |
02B1 Entries in this disk  0000000000000001           |
02B9 Total Entries         0000000000000001           |
02C1 Size of Central Dir   000000000000005E           |
02C9 Offset to Central dir 000000000000023B           |
                                                      |
02D1 ZIP64 END CENTRAL DIR 07064B50                   |
     LOCATOR                                          |
02D5 Central Dir Disk no   00000000                   |
02D9 Offset to Central dir 0000000000000299  ---------+
02E1 Total no of Disks     00000001

02E5 END CENTRAL HEADER    06054B50
02E9 Number of this disk   0000
02EB Central Dir Disk no   0000
02ED Entries in this disk  0001
02EF Total Entries         0001
02F1 Size of Central Dir   0000005E
02F5 Offset to Central Dir FFFFFFFF
02F9 Comment Length        0000
Done
```

EDIT: updated URL for `zipdetails`

Comment: So according to what you just show me the offset is from the 0 byte, so doing like this  "\x50\x4b\x06\x06" in self._fetch_bytes_from_file(source_bucket, source_key, 1811690735, 4200) should bring me the zip64 end central dir record, but I just try it and still doesn't find the "\x50\x4b\x06\x06" on that range of bytes, any other idea?

Comment: Without example code that I can run it is very difficult to tell what the exact problem is. One thing to check --  does your zip file have a comment? If it does, you are going to have to scan backwards from the end of the file to find the EOCD field.

Comment: In theory it doesn't have a comment, cause I can find the ZIP64 END CENTRAL DIR LOCATOR (07064B50) just obtaining 44 bytes starting at the end, if it would have a comment i woudn't find it in that position right?

Comment: Correct - if you can find ZIP64 END CENTRAL DIR LOCATOR at the default offset (42 bytes) from the end of the file you are probably fine. When you read the 8-byte offset to central dir value does the number match the value that zipdetails suggests it should be? Can you check that the little-endian conversion of the 8-byte value is working correctly?

Comment: I tried `zipdetails` a week ago and it didn't work for ZIP>4GB :(
I am going to add a solution for big zip files shortly

Comment: I've tested `zipdetails` with files >4Gig without any problems. Is the zip file publicly available for me to take a look? If there is a bug, I'm keep to get it fixed. BTW - new home for zipdetails is https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails - you might want to try the latest version available there.

Answer (score 0):

The specification of the ZIP format can sometimes be difficult to understand.

The key section is:

```
  4.3.6 Overall .ZIP file format:
  ...
  [central directory header n]
  [zip64 end of central directory record]
  [zip64 end of central directory locator] 
  [end of central directory record]
```

The last three entries have a constant size. From zip64 eocd you can get the information about cd.

When you have all four elements (cd, zip64 eocd record, zip64 eocd locator, eocd), you can open them as a ZIP file and iterate its content.

A solution that works for ZIP files both bigger and smaller than 4GB:

```
import boto3
import io
import struct
import zipfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

EOCD_RECORD_SIZE = 22
ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE = 56
ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE = 20

MAX_STANDARD_ZIP_SIZE = 4_294_967_295

def lambda_handler(event):
    bucket = event['bucket']
    key = event['key']
    zip_file = get_zip_file(bucket, key)
    print_zip_content(zip_file)

def get_zip_file(bucket, key):
    file_size = get_file_size(bucket, key)
    eocd_record = fetch(bucket, key, file_size - EOCD_RECORD_SIZE, EOCD_RECORD_SIZE)
    if file_size <= MAX_STANDARD_ZIP_SIZE:
        cd_start, cd_size = get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd(eocd_record)
        central_directory = fetch(bucket, key, cd_start, cd_size)
        return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + eocd_record))
    else:
        zip64_eocd_record = fetch(bucket, key,
                                  file_size - (EOCD_RECORD_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE),
                                  ZIP64_EOCD_RECORD_SIZE)
        zip64_eocd_locator = fetch(bucket, key,
                                   file_size - (EOCD_RECORD_SIZE + ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE),
                                   ZIP64_EOCD_LOCATOR_SIZE)
        cd_start, cd_size = get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd64(zip64_eocd_record)
        central_directory = fetch(bucket, key, cd_start, cd_size)
        return zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(central_directory + zip64_eocd_record + zip64_eocd_locator + eocd_record))


def get_file_size(bucket, key):
    head_response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return head_response['ContentLength']

def fetch(bucket, key, start, length):
    end = start + length - 1
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (start, end))
    return response['Body'].read()

def get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd(eocd):
    cd_size = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd[12:16])
    cd_start = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd[16:20])
    return cd_start, cd_size

def get_central_directory_metadata_from_eocd64(eocd64):
    cd_size = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd64[40:48])
    cd_start = parse_little_endian_to_int(eocd64[48:56])
    return cd_start, cd_size

def parse_little_endian_to_int(little_endian_bytes):
    format_character = "i" if len(little_endian_bytes) == 4 else "q"
    return struct.unpack("<" + format_character, little_endian_bytes)[0]

def print_zip_content(zip_file):
    files = [zi.filename for zi in zip_file.filelist]
    print(f"Files: {files}")
```